# HTML5 canvas. Draw a line and make it shorter

Tags: html, canvas, grid, coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I have an HTML5 canvas with 0,0 in the upper-left corner.

I draw a line from 10,15, down to 100,300.

Keeping the same slope... what are the 2 end coordinates if I wanted that line to be
10 units shorter on each end?

[image: Simple line drawing]

Answer (score 0):

steps to do this are :
1) get the unit vector of your line.
  ( This is a vector of length 1 having same direction as your line.)
2) add/substract desired length * unit vector to the start/ending point.
3) ... draw the line !

fiddle : 
   http://jsbin.com/vajasibe/1/edit?js,output

step 1, with an on-place function :

```
function buildUnitVector(p1, p2, uVect) {
     uVect.x = (p2.x - p1.x);
     uVect.y = (p2.y - p1.y );
     var vectorNorm = Math.sqrt( sq(uVect.x)+sq(uVect.y) );
     uVect.x/=vectorNorm;
     uVect.y/=vectorNorm;
}
```

with

```
 function sq(x) { return x*x ;}
```

step 2, on-place also :

```
function drawShorterLine(ctx, p1, p2, a, b) {
    buildUnitVector(p1, p2, unitVector);
    sp1.x = p1.x + unitVector.x * a;
    sp1.y = p1.y + unitVector.y * a;
    sp2.x = p2.x - unitVector.x * b;
    sp2.y = p2.y - unitVector.y * b;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(sp1.x, sp1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(sp2.x, sp2.y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
var unitVector = { x:0, y:0 }, sp1 = {x:0,y:0},
            sp2 = {x:0, y:0 } ; 

 // use with
 var p1 = {x:0, y:0}, p2 = {x:100, y:300} ;
 drawShorterLine(ctx, p1, p2, 10, 10);
```